# Take 10 full names (with multiple names) plus many restrictions

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, character

So its a work from school, we need to take up to 10 full names by input ,each full name has to contain at least 3 names (each at least 4 characters long ) maximum of 120 characters per full name , terminating when it reaches the limit or when you write "end" and theres already 5 valid names. After this we need to get the first names of the full names, the last names and random middle names(one of however many there are). We are java noobs and need help.

And from String we can only use the methods: charAt(int), length(), indexOf(…), trim() and subString(…)

this is the code we have right now but it seems we are going nowhere with it the most current problem was that the array gets scrambled somehow.

```
static List<String[]> listarrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
private static Scanner keyboard;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("10 nomes");

    for(int i= 0 ; i<10; i++){

        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        inputtoarray(input);
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("fim") ){
            break;
        }

    }
    String [][] arrayofnames = listtoarray(listarrays);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arrayofnames[1]));
}

public static void SetToArrayString(Set<String> set){
    String[] array = new String[set.size()];
    int index = 0;

    for( String i : set ) {
      array[index++] = i; 
    }
    listarrays.add(array);
}
public static String[][] listtoarray(List<String[]> list){
    String[][] array = new String[list.size()][];
    int index = 0 ;
    for(String[] i : list){
        array[index++] = i;
    }
    String[][] arrayofnames = array; 
    return arrayofnames;
}
public static void inputtoarray(String input){
    int length = 0;
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length(); i++){
        char a_char = input.charAt(i);

        if (a_char == ' '){

            String word1 = input.substring(length,i+1);
            length += word1.length();

            names.add(word1);
        }
        if (i == input.length() - 1){
            String word1 = input.substring(length, i+1);

            names.add(word1);
        }
    }
    P04BaralhadorDeNomes.SetToArrayString(names);
}
```

Please help us or at least give us some advice on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

So in your project are you guaranteed to be given 10 valid names? If so instead of remaking your Array (It is getting scrambled in your method *'inputtoarray'*) you should instantiate it with:

```
//[y-index][x-index]
String[][] nommes = new String[10][3];
```

This would let you simply assign a y-index to another string array containing the names. For that you would have something like this:

```
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
String fist = input.subString(0, input.indexOf(" "));
input = input.subString(input.indexOf(" ") + 1)
// Follow the pattern for the middle and last names
```

What this is doing is taking the input and getting the text up to the space (End of a name). The input line then is substringed so the text that was set to the first name is cut off.

If input was "First Middle Last", first would be equal to "First". Input would then be set to "Middle Last". Repeating what was done for the first name would give you "Middle". Then what you have left is the last name. With your three name values you can make a String array like this:

```
String[] nameParts = new String[]{first, middle, last};
```